# Error on customer confirmation email in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I get receive the confirmation email in inbox as a customer.When i click on link confirm your account it throws error "There was an error confirming the account
" on website.How to fix it.[image: 2]

Comment: please check apache log or Magento logs.

Comment: In error log there is no error for this action.